# Wordpress - Ninja forms edit select values

Tags: wordpress, ninja-forms

I am using Ninja Forms 3.1.4 in a custom Wordpress theme and I am trying to validate and edit a `<select>` value on the server before saving it to the database, example :

```
<select>
  <option value="0">Please select a value</option>
  <option value="1" selected>Option One</option>
  <option value="2">Option Two</option>
</select>
```

On submit, `<option value="1" selected>Option One</option>` being selected, its value will be saved to the database. Which means that if I want to retrieve this information later, in an email notification for example, I will get '**1**'. I would rather show '**Option One**' or something more human friendly.

I would also like to throw an error if the select value is '**0**'.

I found this section in the codex : http://developer.ninjaforms.com/codex/submission-processing-hooks/

So, I tried to implement it like this in my **functions.php** :

```
add_filter('ninja_forms_submit_data', 'edit_select_submit_data');

function edit_select_submit_data($form_data) {

    foreach($form_data['fields'] as $field) {

         /* The doc uses $field['key'] but it seems that
          * I don't have access to it...
          */
        if($field['id'] == '19') { // 19 being my select field ID
            switch($field['value']) {
                case '0':
                    $field['value'] = ''; // Set to empty, so it throws an error
                case '1':
                    $field['value'] = 'Option One'; // Set custom value
                case '2':
                    $field['value'] = 'Option Two'; // Set custom value
            }
        }

    }

    return $form_data;
}
```

This hook is called and code is being executed under the **case '1'**, but the `$field['value']` remains the same and is not updated.

**So, I am wondering if I used the right approach to edit a select field submission value because I can not seem to make it work.**

Answer (score 1):

The example in the codex does not actually work when updating the value of a field, since the `foreach` variable `$field` is not a *reference* to the fields in `$form_data`, but just a copy of the values.

Try doing it like this instead:

```
foreach($form_data['fields'] as $key => $field)
{
    $form_data['fields'][$key]['value'] = 'Custom value';
}
```

That way the actual form data will be updated, and not just the `$field` variable.